# Why don't I get all 4 elements in the same row?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-bootstrap

Please look at the following code:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="first">FIRST</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="first" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="second">SECOND</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="second" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="third">THIRD</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="third" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fourth">FOURTH</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="fourth" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

My purpose was to create a form with 4 elements in ONE line. 
I wrote this code based on this example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h.

However, I got each one of these elements in a different line. Do you know why this code example didn't work out?

Comment: it's working it's showing in one line

Comment: It's working fine and show in one line.. check[ https://jsfiddle.net/e88eqL0o/

Comment: I think your window is not large enough, so it automatically adds rows for the different divs

Comment: Issue can be because of either your small viewport or some of your custom style has overridden it

Comment: This is a part of a big code repository. The code snippet I wrote is placed inside the following tags: 

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 ">
      <div class="portlet-body form">
         <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-body">
               <form name="Form" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
                   <!-- MY LINES -->
               ... closing tags ... 

maybe the surrounding tags caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need add these scripts and CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the answer. The browser doesn't recognize the bootstrap's classes, and instead of giving an error, it just ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing your form on a viewport of more than 768px width, it will appear in one line. Otherwise it will not.

Test this out with the demo of `inline-form` on bootstraps website on [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) link

Excerpt from the above link!

> Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for left-aligned and inline-block controls. This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.

Here is [a plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWb9lCVWMS335zCiWZnL?p=preview) that shows that your code when viewed in bigger screens shows up in one line. Click on the full screen link in the plunker and see the result.

Check if your parent container has a width set that is less than 768px.

Comment: I am watching this page with a 1920px wide screen.

Comment: How does this form look in your screen? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline Its the exact same thing. Try resizing it to less than 768px and you can see the fields going vertical

Comment: it shows in one-line and once I reduce the screen size, it's moving verticle.

Comment: Correct. It really is crazy as you have almost the same code as that demo. Let me try something now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html ng-app="">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="first">FIRST</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="first" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="second">SECOND</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="second" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="third">THIRD</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="third" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fourth">FOURTH</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="fourth" ng-model="???" ng-readonly="true" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives you all four in one line...

> you have missed div class="col-xs-12" that means all content should
>   be in one row,
>   one row have maximum 12 col-xs that we declared.

and i have just tried for you and it is giving me the output like:
[image]

Comment: I tried it. It didn't help. It also doesn't show in the example.

Comment: just copy my code in any html file and just run it because it is working for me

Answer (score -1):

i think they are too large for the window , try resizing the input boxes to fit the window in one line

or

try this put all the 4 elements in one 'div' tag , i think after displaying one div tag it goes to the next line by default, so use only one div tag